# Adding 1 kg on dumbell on only one side

Tags: bodybuilding, workout

I do workouts in my home and i have only 18 kg of weight plates in total. I do bicep exercises using dumbbells with equal weight plates on each side. My question is, can I add a 1 kg plate on one side only if I don't have weight plates to equally balance both sides of the dumbbell? Will it be okay for biceps, and triceps too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing, with the question involving adding weight plates, you may actually be referring to barbells, not dumbbells (dumbbells are cast in one piece generally). First, they do sell half-kilo plates, so that might be the best option to allow yourself some degree of gradation in increasing weight. Secondly, uneven loading of barbells is done, although usually with a single bar, as per [this SE answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/14377/8039).

My impulse is that you would have an additional strain on your wrists and a less degree of forearm strain in a traditional curl. If your tricep exercise is something like the traditional arm extension, the effect may be less since the natural way to do that exercise has one side dipping lower already. I would advise doing the movement slowly and carefully, taking care to keep your wrist stable, especially at first, but otherwise, you're essentially adding a wrist workout to your biceps or triceps exercise.

Comment: no i am talking about dumbbells and i can load plates on it.I want to do dumbbell curl with 15 kg but dont have 1/2 kilo weight so i would have to increase by 2 kilos every time i want to do progressive overload but 2kg is too much for me so i was saying if it could not be a problem to add 1kg plate on one side only while leaving other as it is.

Comment: {nods} Alright. Well, the rest of my answer fits, in that it will create an additional strain on your wrist for you to keep them aligned. It's not inherently harmful, but could cause injury if your wrists aren't up to it. And, as I noted, the typical tricep extension exercise will be unaffected.